# What is the maximum temperature at which cream will still whip successfully?

Tags: dessert, cream, whipped-cream

I recently tried to whip warm cream and was surprised to find out that it would not hold air. After some limited research, I have discovered that in order for the fat in cream to form the matrix and hold air it must be cold.

What is the event horizon at which the cream is too warm to be whipped?

Comment: +1 But if it is at the event horizon ... How could you know if it isn't already whipped?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ideal temperature for whipping cream is between 35 degrees F and 50 degrees F (1 2/3 degrees C to 10 degrees C).  In order to maintain this temperature, you may want to chill your bowl and beaters in your fridge until cold, but you should be able to whip cream just fine as long as you do not let it rest once you remove it from the fridge.

Above 50 degrees F (10 degrees C) you won't be able to whip your cream.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the (essentially) instant response time! I think I will be visiting this community more often!